# C++ destructors and PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Are destructors for automatic objects guaranteed to execute if a thread is cancelled asynchronously?

Comment: This would depend on your platform and compiler. The C++ standard does not know the existence of PThreads. What platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific with the question. What automatic objects what threading system how are you cancelling the thread?

Comment: Thanks Roddy, this was due to ignorance on my part, not negligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, it SHOULD work fine, but it's worth testing with your platform.

Cancelling a thread eventually ends up invoking `pthread_exit()`, which as far as I can tell from googling will invoke destructors. It does this by throwing some kind of 'guaranteed uncaught' exception all the way out to the thread wrapper, so all your stack-based objects get destructed in the correct order.

See [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2928/index.htm?info/apis/users_18.htm), for example. And [this blog post](http://www.alexonlinux.com/pthread_exit-in-c):

> When calling pthread_exit() in C++, it
>   has to destruct all objects that has
>   been created on stack. This process
>   called stack unwinding and this is
>   exactly what happens when you throw an
>   exception. pthread_exit() utilizes
>   this feature of C++ to cleanup before
>   shutting down the thread for good.
>
> To do that pthread_exit() throws some
>   obscure exception and catches it right
>   before ditching the thread. This way
>   it cleans up all objects nicely. On
>   the other hand, catching … becomes
>   impossible.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  Regarding that blog post, I assume the catch ... is not an issue if the try block simply returns from the thread function rather than directly calling pthread_exit()?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ill-formed.  There are no "threads" in standard C++ prior to C++0x, and there is no asynchronous cancellation of threads in C++0x.  So there is no answer to your question outside the particular C++ and pthreads implementation you happen to be using.

That said, the answer on your implementation is probably "no".  (At least, I am unaware of any implementations where the answer is yes.)

[edit]

OK, so my knowledge is out of date.  On Linux at least with a modern threading library, the stack is generally unwound (per @Roddy's answer).

It is still true that this behavior is not guaranteed by any standard, however.

Comment: It's pthreads. That's pretty clear from the tags and title. And that's a posix standard AFAIK.

Comment: @Roddy: Yes, but POSIX threads are a C interface, not a C++ interface.  So the POSIX standard says exactly nothing about this question.

Comment: I'm concerned with the implementation Linux rather than what the standard specifies.  Standards are rarely implemented 100.0% to spec.

Comment: @Borislav:  Fine, but you should always write your code to standards where possible, since 90% of the cost of all software is maintenance.  Just because something happens to work on your particular machine today does not mean it will work where you want to run your code tomorrow.  (And for the record, asynchronous thread cancellation is almost indicative of a poor and fragile design.  That is why C++0x threads do not support cancellation...)

Comment: Nemo, I've been reading discussions including people like Anthony Williams who designed much of the C++0x threading, and the reason synchronous/coooperative interruption was not supported is due to disagreement on various details rather than being able to do it at all. Thread interruption is also part of Boost threads. So it's misleading to say that is why C++0x threads do not support cancellation. Perhaps what you meant to write is that they do not support _asynchronous_ cancellation, which may well be the case. [continued]

Comment: [continued] However, a standard can't cover every situation and it's with good reason std::thread allows one to get the native handle. Some of the threads I run are running code I did not produce and can well be considered a black box, so I cannot assume that synchronous cancellation is sufficient and the main application needs to, by specification, be able to restart them in some conditions if they hagg without restarting the whole process. I cannot simply make them separate processes due to significant shared memory (tried shmem and it's too slow) and thread pool task based scheduling.

Comment: @Borislav: But if the code is a "black box", that is even worse, because then you _never_ know whether asynchronous cancellation is dangerous.  Not all C++ code (especially inside the "black box") is written to use RAII, and even when it is, the system libraries are usually written in C.  As a trivial example, what if you cancel a thread in the middle of malloc() while it holds the heap mutex?  You may be taking on an impossible problem, I fear...

Answer (score 1):

Technically I think this is a quality-of-implementation question: the C++ standard doesn't address POSIX threads, and the POSIX threading standard is a C-language binding that doesn't address C++.

So, in principle, a C++ implementation could make this work (it could even guarantee it).  In practice, I'd be surprised if it worked with either deferred or asynchronous cancellation.