# pthread memory leak with stack variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, pthreads

I have noticed that when I call a method using a thread in the form

```
////main code/////
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(thread,function,data);
//////////////////

void* function(void* data){

    //work with some data on the heap via a vector on the stack

    std::vector<double> variable (100,1.2345);

    //do contents of thread

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

despite having no calls to `new` (except implicitly in vector variable) I get a memory leak  with the amount of memory usage going linearly with the number of times I call `function` in this way.

However if I do this

```
void* function(void* data){

    {
    std::vector<double> variable (100,1.2345);

    //do contents of thread
     }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

the memory leak doesn't occur.

It seems that `pthread_exit(NULL)`doesn't clear the stack variables like you would get at the end of a normal function with `return` (I am correct about that right?!) so putting them within their own scope ensures they get freed.

However, this seems like a massive kludge. How do I ensure the stack variables (and their contents on the heap in terms of containers) are cleared properly when exiting a pthread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6589003/4082723

Comment: What platform? What compiler options? (For some reason, your stack is not getting unwound. It could be because you aren't specifying the compiler options your platform requires.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems that `pthread_exit(NULL)` doesn't clear the stack variables like you would get at the end of a normal function with return (I am correct about that right?!)

That's like calling `exit(0)` in non-threaded code, the program exits right away  and doesn't unwind the stack. (Since the pthreads spec is defined in terms of C, not C++, it doesn't define what happens with C++ destructors, so it's platform specific).

> so putting them within their own scope ensures they get freed.

Because that way the vector's destructor runs before you call `pthread_exit()`.

> How do I ensure the stack variables (and their contents on the heap in terms of containers) are cleared properly when exiting a pthread?

Just return from the thread function, you don't need to use `pthread_exit` to exit from the thread start function (the one that was passed to `pthread_create`). [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html) says:

> An implicit call to `pthread_exit()` is made when a thread other than the thread in which `main()` was first invoked returns from the start routine that was used to create it.

and the [GNU/Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) says the same thing slightly differently:

> Performing a return from the start function of any thread other than
>          the main thread results in an implicit call to `pthread_exit()`, using
>          the function's return value as the thread's exit status.

You can use `pthread_exit` to exit the thread from other functions further down the stack, just like you can use `exit()` to quit a program instead of returning from `main()`, but at the outermost function just `return NULL;` (or whatever return value you want).

The only time using `pthread_exit(x)` makes a difference to simply `return x;` is in `main` where it will cause the program to wait until other threads finish.

Comment: Ah, I see, for some reason I had it in my head that you needed to call `pthread_exit()` hence the confusion. Tested this and it solves it. Thanks.

Comment: To add to that, another source of possible leaks is if the pthread is created as a joinable thread (the default), a thread keeps resources around(often the entire stack of the thread) until someone else calls pthread_join() on that thread - so make sure the thread is either a detached thread, or make sure someone call pthread_join() on it.

Answer (score 1):

(Okay, I can see that someone else addressed this issue already... And yes, this only applies to joinable threads. If you try to detach a **non-joinable** thread you raise an error.)

You'll need to call `pthread_detach(...)` to configure the pthread for resource reclamation on exit.

[pthread_detach documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html)

This is not to invalidate any of the other answers. However, **you'll need to detach any joinable child thread that you don't join**, if you want its stack space to be reclaimed when it exits! Why would you ever not want that?

Even if you solve this particular leak with a code change, you'll need to move forward with this awareness if you are going to program with child threads in C/C++. `std::thread` and `boost::thread` have similar requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The calls to `new()` are hidden in the `std::vector<>` implementation.

In your first code sample `pthread_exit(NULL);` will exit the thread, before the `std::vector<>` destructor is called, thus the memory leaks.

Your second example forces the destructor of the `std::vector<>` is called before `pthread_exit(NULL);`.